# Don't see data from django in reactjs frontend

Tags: reactjs, django

I am new at react. And I am building django + react web-application
Full code of the project https://github.com/mascai/django_examples/tree/master/02_django_react

When I make request to `http://127.0.0.1:8001/api/lead/` i see valid data from Django.
But whe I go to `http://127.0.0.1:8001` I don't see don't see any data.

I think that problem with frontend side.

**index.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { render } from "react-dom";

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      data: [],
      loaded: false,
      placeholder: "Loading"
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch("api/lead")
      .then(response => {
        if (response.status > 400) {
          return this.setState(() => {
            return { placeholder: "Something went wrong!" };
          });
        } 
        return response.json();
      })
      .then(data => {
        this.setState(() => {
          return {
            data,
            loaded: true
          };
        });
      });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <ul>
        {this.state.data.map(contact => {
          return (
            <li key={contact.id}>
              {contact.name} - {contact.email}
            </li>
          );
        })}
      </ul>
    );
  }
}

export default App;

const container = document.getElementById("app");
render(<App />, container);
```

**index.html** (seems fine)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Django REST with React
</head>
<body>
<div id="app">
    <!-- React will load here -->
</div>
</body>
{% load static %}
<script src="{% static "frontend/main.js" %}"></script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot a closing tag for *title* in your `index.html`:

```html
<title>Django REST with React</title>
```

and the script quotes should be like this (notice the double and single quotes):

```html
<script src="{% static 'frontend/main.js' %}"></script>
```

Another problem is that when you build your React app, it will be placed inside `static/frontend/main.js/main.js`. So not only you are creating a file with name `main.js`, but also a directory called `main.js`.

In order to fix this, first delete the contents of `static/frontend` folder (delete the `main.js` directory).

Then go to `package.json` and change the output path in your scripts to

```
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "webpack --mode development ./src/index.js --output-path ./static/frontend",
    "build": "webpack --mode production ./src/index.js --output-path ./static/frontend"
  },
```

I also suggest to put an `<h1>` tag with random text into your component so that you can see if your component actually renders.

Finally compile your react app using one of the two commands.